# Multioutput regression with differing results when explicitly creating individual output neurons

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, regression

I have a neural network model defined as such:

```
class FDC_Model(Model):
    def __init__(self, out_names):
        super(FDC_Model, self).__init__()
        self.out_names = out_names
        self.n_outputs = len(self.out_names)

        self.fc1 = Dense(units=35, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="FC1")
        self.dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.22, name="dropout1")
        self.fc2 = Dense(units=31, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="FC2")
        self.dropout2 = Dropout(rate=0.32, name="dropout2")
        
        self.fc3 = []
        for name in self.out_names:
            fc3 = Dense(units=1, activation="linear", name=name)
            self.fc3.append(fc3)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        base = self.fc1(inputs)
        base = self.dropout1(base)
        base = self.fc2(base)
        base = self.dropout2(base)
        outputs = []
        for i in range(len(self.out_names)):
            output_neuron = self.fc3[i](base)
            outputs.append(output_neuron)
        return outputs
```

A model with hidden Dense layers of 35 and 31 units each. In the future, I wish to apply different loss functions for each output neuron, hence the for-loop to define Dense layers of 1-unit each. In the call function, the model is assembled, and the output neurons are attached to the base model, then combined into a list.

The assembly and fit functions is as follows:

```
fdc_model = FDC_Model(list(y_data.columns))  # There are 15 output columns
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(len(x_data.columns)), name='input layer')
outputs = fdc_model.call(inputs)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.002),
              metrics=['mae'])

history = model.fit(
        x=x_train_np,  # shape is (1600, 170) for 1600 rows and 170 features
        y=y_train_np,  # shape is (400, 170) for 400 rows and 15 outputs
        batch_size=300,
        epochs=400,
        validation_data=(x_val_np, y_val_np),
        verbose=0
    )
```

The model trains, converges to both training and validations losses of ~0.9 MSE, and I do a prediction:

```
x_testingdata = x_data_np[3,]
x_testingdata = x_testingdata.reshape(1, -1)  # shape would be (1, 168)
model.predict(x_testingdata)

# Result:
[array([[-2.350444]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3502371]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3503947]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3501287]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3503363]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.350448]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3504179]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3504128]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3505998]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3502173]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3502579]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3505251]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3503647]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-2.3503902]], dtype=float32)]
```

The expected pattern is a set of numbers that are monotonically increasing, which this obviously does not possess. Concerned that each output element are so similar to each other, I investigate further, and replace the for loop with a single dense layer of 15 units (the number of columns in my y data) as my output:

```
class FDC_Model(Model):
    def __init__(self, out_names):
        super(FDC_Model, self).__init__()
        self.out_names = out_names
        self.n_outputs = len(self.out_names)

        self.fc1 = Dense(units=35, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="FC1")
        self.dropout1 = Dropout(rate=0.22, name="dropout1")
        self.fc2 = Dense(units=31, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="he_uniform", name="FC2")
        self.dropout2 = Dropout(rate=0.32, name="dropout2")

        self.output_layer = Dense(units=self.n_outputs, activation="linear")
        
    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        base = self.fc1(inputs)
        base = self.dropout1(base)
        base = self.fc2(base)
        base = self.dropout2(base)
        base = self.output_layer(base)
        return base
```

The model-creation and fit functions are unchanged, and this time I get a different result with overall training/validation loss of about ~0.1 MSE:

```
x_testingdata = x_data_np[3,]
x_testingdata = x_testingdata.reshape(1, -1)  # shape would be (1, 168)
model.predict(x_testingdata)

# Result:
array([[-3.8779106 , -3.7076812 , -3.376519  , -3.222118  , -3.0211792 ,
    -2.8465135 , -2.6778078 , -2.5099883 , -2.3385167 , -2.154858  ,
    -1.9535067 , -1.7082998 , -1.5430773 , -1.1735327 , -0.94434386]],
  dtype=float32)
```

The result is more in-line with what I expected, so now I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding how the creating of Dense layers works and I am somehow duplicating Dense layers in the for loop, or if I attached the Dense layers improperly.

EDIT: I manually wrote out all fifteen layers in separate Dense functions, attached them all to the same base model, and got the same result as above. So it's something to do with how I'm attaching them to the base model.